# DataGridView en VBnet

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I don't know how to pass different DataGridViews according to the name put in a Sub.

I have multiple forms with multiple DataGridViews (Movements / SubMoves / Categories

I want to use Name for each of the DataGridView.

ex:

```
Sub Colorcell(**Nombre** As String , Fore As Color, Back As Color, Fil As Integer, Col As Integer, Fuente As FontStyle)
 
        With **Nombre**
            Dim Celda As DataGridViewCell = .Rows(Fil).Cells(Col)
            Celda.Style.Font = New Font(Celda.InheritedStyle.Font, Fuente)
            .Rows(Fil).Cells(Col).Style.ForeColor = Fore
            .Rows(Fil).Cells(Col).Style.BackColor = Back

        End With
 End Sub
```

Comment: El idioma de Stack Overflow es el inglés. Publique su pregunta en inglés, o con una traducción al inglés, si desea recibir ayuda aquí. Es posible que desee publicar su pregunta en [Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com) en su lugar.  The language of Stack Overflow is English. Please post your question in English, or with an English translation, if you wish to receive help here. You may wish to post your question on Stack Overflow en Español instead.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because It is not in English. Voto para cerrar esta pregunta porque no está en inglés.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Module in your project like 'DataGridViewHelper.cs' then extends the DataGridView class

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module DataGridViewHelper

    <Extension>
    Public Sub Colorcell(dgv As DataGridView, Fore As Color, Back As Color, Fil As Integer, Col As Integer, Fuente As FontStyle)
        Dim Celda As DataGridViewCell = dgv.Rows(Fil).Cells(Col)
        Celda.Style.Font = New Font(Celda.InheritedStyle.Font, Fuente)
        Celda.Style.ForeColor = Fore
        Celda.Style.BackColor = Back
    End Sub

End Module
```

And you call it like that :

```
dgvMovements.ColorCell(myForeColor, myBackColor, indexRow, indexCol, myFont)
```